# Calculate area of overlap within polygons

Tags: arcgis-pro, land-classification

ArcGIS Pro 10.6

I have a polygon layer with a column of 5 unique values, class names. 
I have a second polygon layer with a column of unique values, Parcel number.

Each parcel will have multiple classes within its bounds.

I need a layer where each parcel appears once and is associated with the area of each class within its bounds.

I have tried pivots, intersects, merges, tabulations... the list goes on. Somebody save my sanity please.

Comment: You want the parcel geometries unchanged but with 5 new columns with each class area?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I understand the theory but it’s not translating to reality well. All of my column values get shifted around and my parcel id column disappears. I am using Class Name as the pivot field, Parcel ID as the value field and all other fields as input fields. Based on the Pivot Table illustration from ESRI this should be correct, no?

Comment: You are not following step 2. You should only use the three fields as described

Comment: I will respond more thoroughly when I’m able but this approach does not work for me. I will continue trying some things and uploading what I’m looking at. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: There is no such thing as ArcGIS Pro 10.6. What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using or are you actually using the ArcMap application of ArcGIS Desktop 10.6?

Answer (score 1):

1. Intersect the two polygon feature classes
2. Pivot Table on Intersect output with parcel number as `Input Field(s)`, the one column/field holding the 5 unique values as `Pivot Field` and Shape_Area as `Value Field`
3. Join this table back to the Parcels using parcel number as join fields
4. Export/Copy Features to save the joined tables